# Sorting a custom type array by a string attribute?

Tags: java, string, sorting

I have an array of a custom type that I want to sort by one of its String attributes. For some reason, the following code is producing wrong results. Could you point out where I might have made a mistake?

```
class PatientLNComparator implements Comparator<Patient>{
        @Override
        public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) {
            String p1_LN = (p1 == null) ? null : p1.last_name;
            String p2_LN = (p2 == null) ? null : p2.last_name;

            if(p2_LN == null)
                    return -1;
            else if(p1_LN == null)
                    return +1;
            else if(p1_LN.equals(p2_LN))
                    return 0;
            else if(p1_LN.compareTo(p2_LN) > 0)
                    return -1;
            else
                    return +1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the wrong results?  prima facie i think you flipped the sign in the compareTo line

Comment: Since all the null checks are being done first, you can get rid of `p2_LN` and `p1_LN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem to start with - your comparator is inconsistent if you give it two patients with null names, or two null patient references. In particular:

```
Patient p1 = null;
Patient p2 = null;

int x = comparator.compare(p1, p2);
int y = comparator.compare(p2, p1);
```

The signs of `x` and `y` *ought* to be different - but they'll both be -1.

After that, it depends on how you want to compare the names. I would usually use

```
return p1_LN.compareTo(p2_LN);
```

if you want to sort in ascending order. Note that to sort in *descending* order you shouldn't just return `-p1_LN.compareTo(p2_LN)`, as if the comparison returns the Integer.MIN_VALUE, the negation won't work. Instead you'd want to return `p2_LN.compareTo(p1_LN);`.

Note that if you're using this scheme, you don't need to call `p1_LN.equals(p2_LN)` either - that will be handled by the `compareTo` call.

Comment: You mean `int y = comparator.compare(p2, p1);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want natural string ordering for this.

First of all, as it is, your compareTo branch is giving inversed results. Don't know if that's what you intended or not (as in you're saying p1 is greater than p2 when the p1's string is lower than p2's).

Furthermore, you can ditch the .equals branch of the if. The compareTo already handles this case.

Therefore a simple

```
if(p2_LN == null && p1_LN == null)
    return 0;
else if(p1_LN == null)
    return +1;
else if(p2_LN == null)
    return -1;
else return p1_LN.compareTo(p2_LN)
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You want patient to be ordered by alphabetical by last name, null patients and null last names up front?

```
class PatientLNComparator implements Comparator<Patient>{
        @Override
        public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) {
            String p1_LN = (p1 == null) ? null : p1.last_name;
            String p2_LN = (p2 == null) ? null : p2.last_name;

            if (p1_LN == null && p2_LN == null)
                    return 0;
            else if (p2_LN == null)
                    return -1;
            else if(p1_LN == null)
                    return +1;
            else
                    return p1_LN.compareTo(p2_LN);
        }
}
```

To be stable, it really should order by some other fields, like first name, when last names are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Ordering](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class for this:

```
class Patient {
    // ...
    public static final Function<Patient, String> GET_LAST_NAME =
        new Function<Patient, String>() {
            public String apply(Patient from) {
                if (from == null) return null;
                return from.last_name;
            }
        };

    public static final Comparator<Patient> BY_LAST_NAME =
        Ordering.natural()
                .onResultOf(GET_LAST_NAME)
                .nullsFirst();
}
```

This will resolve the issue with inconsistent comparison of nulls.  It also makes it easy to add a secondary order (e.g. first name):

```
    public static final Comparator<Patient> BY_LAST_NAME =
        Ordering.natural()
                .onResultOf(GET_LAST_NAME)
                .compound(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(GET_FIRST_NAME))
                .nullsFirst();
```